# Does checking the instanceof a class inside another class have some negative side effect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oop, es6-class

I am using ES6 Class, and I have a method like this

```
 wrapAsync(fn) {
    return (req, res) =>
      fn(req, res).catch((error) => {
        return this.HttpError({
          statusCode: error instanceof UniqueError ? 409 : error instanceof InvalidPropertyError ? 400 : 500,
          title: error.name,
          message: error.message,
          stack: error.stack
        })
      })
  }
```

The status code is set based on the instance of which error was thrown, hence this `statusCode: error instanceof UniqueError ? 409: error instanceof InvalidPropertyError ? 400 : 500`. But I noticed that the ternary operator value always resulted in the falsy value, in this case, the status code always comes out as 500 even though the error is thrown is an instance of `UniqueError` which in this case, the status code is meant to be 409. Any idea why this might be so?

The definition of `InvalidPropertyError` and `UniqueError` looks like this

```
class InvalidPropertyError extends Error {
  constructor(msg) {
    super(msg)

    this.name = 'InvalidPropertyError'
    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, InvalidPropertyError)
    }
  }
}
```

```
class UniqueConstraintError extends Error {
  constructor(value) {
    super(`${value} must be unique.`)

    this.name = 'UniqueConstraintError'
    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, UniqueConstraintError)
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see from the above definition, I am just inheriting from the Base Error class. So somewhere in my program, I could just do an error check and throw the appropriate error. For example, assuming I am checking if a name exists or not, I just do this

```
...
const exist = await usersDb.find({name})
if(exist) throw UniqueError('Name already exist')
...
```

Now `fn(req, res)` is just meant to act as a middleware that will catch all errors thrown from any layer of the program, which is implemented like this.

```
const myFunc = ({ someDep }) => {
  return http.wrapAsync(async (httpRequest) => {
    const { user } = httpRequest
    const { ...details } = httpRequest.body

    await someDep({ user, ...details })
    return http.apiResponse({
      status: true,
      message: 'successful',
      data: null,
      statusCode: 200
    })
  })
}
```

So that's how `wrapAsync` is implemented. It just wraps all async operations and catches any error that is being thrown.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the type really is what you think it is. Do `console.log(error instanceof UniqueError)` to debug.

Comment: We would need to see the definitions of `InvalidPropertyError` and `UniqueError`, as well as look at what kind of error `fn(req, res)` would throw, to help you further.

Comment: @JosephHall I edited the question to explain in detail. Thank you :-)